# I want to inherit concrete level classes to abstract class at run time in c#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, windows-forms-designer, generalization

I am working on c# windows form. I want to do class generalization from given input code by generating an abstract class for common properties of all classes given in input and then other classes are inherited with that abstract class. I am successfully getting abstract class but I don't know how to inherit other classes with that base class so that I can also get those classes in output.

Comment: Can you show us some code that you have done already?

Comment: I don't understand the title. Do you say that you want to generate C# code and type def at runtime?